# How to save temp data

Tags: command-line

**updated:**

I'd like to save a large amount data ( ~ 100MB ) from *the standard input* in **temporary** location for the duration of my bash session.

Piping it to a *file* won't work as I have only 30MB of free space. I also don't want to save it in a *variable*.

I'd obviously have to utilize some space other than that of my *Disk Storage*. Which leaves my *RAM*.

Is there some *mechanism* that will allow me to write to it, and then to retreive the written data again. ( like when you pipe to and from `/dev/null` )

Comment: It appears you want to do this from a shell. Also, do you want the data to be locked in ram? That is to NEVER get swapped out?

Comment: @kbyrd, updated the question, hope it makes more sense now  :)

Comment: I'm unclear about how krissi's answer doesn't address this.  His answer provides a mechanism for writing to ram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can mount an ramfs and store data there (as a file)

```
# mkdir /media/ram
# mount -t ramfs none /media/ram
# <texfile grep pattern > /media/ram/ram
# cat /media/ram/ram
# umount /media/ram
```

Comment: Stefan: this sounds like exactly what you're looking for - /media/ram will act like a device (like /dev/null), and will take up no disk space: any files you create in that directory will only be created "in memory" (i.e. in your RAM), and will be lost when you unmount /media/ram in the last step.

Comment: and thus it has been accepted